# ES5<=>ES6の変換ツール

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

http://js2.coffee/

このツールは`JavaScript <=> CoffeScript`の相互変換のツールですが、
同じように`JavaScript <=> ES6`に変換できるものはありませんか?

目的はすでにある`JS`のコードを効率よく`ES6`に置き換えたいというものです。

`ES6`では`JS(ES5)`のシンタックスも通ってしまうため難しいとは思いますが、
より`ES6`らしく書く手助けになるツールがあればと思い質問させていただきました。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

ES6を、現行のブラウザで動くJavaScriptに変換するツールは、[Babel](https://babeljs.io/)などの定番transpilerがありますね。

逆方向(JavaScriptをモダンに書き換える)は、ぐぐってみたら[Lebab](http://lebab.io/) というのを見つけました。

Answer (score 2):

ESLint の自動修正機能を使うのもひとつの手です。
[no-var](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var), [prefer-const](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const), [prefer-arrow-callback](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback), [object-shorthand](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand) 等、自動修正によって ES5 のコードを ES2015 (ES6) に直してくれるルールがあります。

参考: [ES6ルール一覧](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/#ecmascript-6), [ESLint最初の一歩](http://qiita.com/mysticatea/items/f523dab04a25f617c87d)